# Completely capture output of call to GNU screen

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

In a Python 3 program of mine, I open a GNU screen session at some point. 
Upon closing this session, the output

```
[screen is terminating]
```

is printed to the surrounding session (the terminal in which the python program is run). How do I prevent this?

I am currently running something like

```
import subprocess 
subprocess.run('screen',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Usually, the `[stdout,stderr]=subprocess.PIPE` captures the output and err (e.g. for `run('echo hello',stdout=subprocess.PIPE)` nothing is printed) but for some reason this doesn't work with `screen`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should capture `stderr` as well as `stdout`, if you don't want anything printed on the console.

`Screen` may also be detecting that `stdin` is a tty and using that for I/O. I don't know if giving it a pipe or `/dev/null` will solve the problem, though. Try it and see if it works.

`Screen` most likely needs access to a `tty` device to work. You could create a tty for it (by opening `/dev/ptmx` and giving `screen` the corresponding `/dev/pts/N` file), but that's by no means trivial.

Comment: I believe you are right. When I change the `stdin` I do get `stdout` content namely ''screen must be connected to a temrinal" (or something like that)". What you propose is too difficult for me, I believe. I have another solution: Just delete what was written using `'\b', '\033[F', '\033[K' `. Unfortunately `screen` does not always end with the same output to the terminal, do you know of a way to read what screen has printed to the terminal?